# Extract native libraries to /var/task/lib Node.js lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Apparently the LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes /var/task/lib.

But how do I make sure my libs end up in /var/task/lib.

All my code ends up in /var/task/hello-world.

Comment: If you can give more details about the actual problem, then we can help more. For example, what language are you using, what library you want to add and why do you want to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Lambda deployment package (zip file with your code) is extracted to `/var/task` with its directory structure intact.  If you want something in `/var/task/lib/`, put it inside `lib/` and not the root of the zip file.

> *All my code ends up in /var/task/hello-world*

This implies that you have a folder named `hello-world` in the root of your zip file.  Your code needs to go in the root of the zip, not in a folder, unless you specifically want it to be extracted to a folder under `/var/task`, as noted above.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-deployment-package-nodejs/